# Copying from and to text file using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

I need to know how can i save text from a `javax.swing.JTextArea` using `javax.swing.JFileChooser`. I tried different things but i am not able to save the data from the JTextArea. And also copy from one text file to another using JFileChooser. Please help, I am relatively new to java.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson of the Java Tutorial with particular attention to [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

For more specific advice, you would need to ask more specific questions, or *any* questions, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

JTextArea has read(...) and write(...) methods that you should be using.

A JFileChooser is just for getting the file name and has nothing to do with file I/O.

Copying data is a different story and Andrew has given you links to the tutorial on using file I/O.